# how to convert sparse numpy array to Dataframe?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

below is the code snippet,

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[2,3,4])],remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(x_data))
X.shape
```

i get output like below for shape

```
()
```

when i try to print X , I get output like below

```
array(<8820x35 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 41527 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

now when i try to convert this array to dataframe

```
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

i get below error

```
ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

how do i convert my numpy array to dataframe?

Comment: @FadingOrigami Please don't post answers as comments. You miss out on reputation and other people will think the question is not answered while it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
ct.fit_transform(x_data)
```

produces a sparse matrix.

```
np.array(...)
```

just wraps that in a object dtype array.

```
array(<8820x35 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 41527 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

Use `toarray` or `A` to convert it properly to a numpy array:

```
X = ct.fit_transform(x_data).A
```

Answer (score 2):

So first, convert the sparse matrix from csr_matrix to a normal array

```
 X = X.toarray()
 df  = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

The above should work

Comment: i tried the method you gave but i get errorlike this 
`
"AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tocsc"
any idea?

Comment: Hi, @pramod I have edited the answer to fix the issue. Also if the answer above works, I'd appreciate it if you accept the answer as the right one.